# ffmpeg command line error in MacOS Mojave: dyld: BIND_OPCODE_DO_BIND

Tags: macos, command-line, ffmpeg, homebrew, macos-mojave

I have a problem with the command line ffmpeg throwing an error whenever it is run.

I'm a long time video / mac / occasional linux user so I'm at home in CLI, but have very definite limits to my knowledge!

The error looks like this:

```
$ ffmpeg
dyld: BIND_OPCODE_DO_BIND missing preceding BIND_OPCODE_SET_SYMBOL_TRAILING_FLAGS_IMM in /usr/local/opt/libunistring/lib/libunistring.2.dylib
Abort trap: 6
```

The Mac I'm seeing the problem with has recently been re-installed using time machine and I'm wondering if this has broken some of my command line tools.

Since that OS re-install ffmpeg has been installed (and re-installed) using homebrew. I've updated, upgrade and cleaned brew itself, and re-installed the xcode command line tools.

I don't really understand where the error is coming from and would very much like it if people can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have found a fix for this particular problem.

using brew command

```
brew reinstall libunistring
```

Seems to have fixed the symptom, and ffmpeg now responds more like I expect it to.

I think this may be to do with weird things that happen when you restore a mac using Time Machine, AND have made a bunch of xcode / brew / ruby changes to the default installation. Certainly things are smoother now I've been reinstalling / resetting cli business.

Thanks for reading